# *UPDATE* Crystal Reports: Select Expert Formula not pulling all data

Tags: crystal-reports

gurus.

I have below formula that I have been at it for a while now.

```
 ({?Position}='ALL' or {Command.category} like {?Position} & "*") and
 ({?Day_Night}='ALL' or {?Day_Night}={command.day} or {?Day_Night}= 
 {command.night})
```

The formula only works for two selections, "All" and "day", but the "night" selection doesn't show all the data. I have also tried pairing the position and day selections, but it did not work.

*UPDATE*
So what I noticed is that when the "Night" parameter is selected, the report is omitting any NULL record for the Day field. the Day field could either be NULL or not, so the Night parameter needs to count the day reocrds as long as the night is greater than 0. The Day parameter doesn't do this and I don't know why?

Another formula that I tried:

```
if {?Day_Night} = 'All' then  
({?Position}='ALL' or {Command.category} like {?Position} & "*") and {? 
Day_Night}='All'
else if {?Day_Night}={command.day} then
({?Position}='ALL' or {Command.category} like {?Position} & "*") and {? 
Day_Night}={command.day}
else if {?Day_Night}={command.night} then
({?Position}='ALL' or {Command.category} like {?Position} & "*") and ({? 
Day_Night}={command.night} and 
(not isnull({Command.day}) or isnull({Command.Day}))
)
```

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: are you comparing parameter with a database field?

Comment: I look at the total number of records selected from each parameter and comparing it with what I get from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula doesn't make any sense to me as you are directly comparing parameter field to database field, which won't return any result.

Normally select expert need to be used to fetch data from database, so your case would be. Take below as the example.

```
if {?Day_Night}="day"
Then {command.day}
```

This will fetch data, in the same way for night aswell.

Comment: I added another formula that I tried, but the night parameter still does not select everything that it needs to.

Comment: What are the possible values for `{?Day_Night}`

Comment: The report's SQL is to sort for any record that has payhour_night > 0. The same thing for payhour_day > 0. so when "Night" is selected as a parameter, the report is supposed to show the night records. Sometimes a record can have the "Day" as null, but the "Night", not null. The report should show such a record, but right now it isn't. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: This is a wrong way you need to give this `{?Position}` in IF not in Then

Answer (score 0):

Once I checked the box for "default values for Null" in the report options section, the report began to pull the correct number of records. I feel so stupid that the answer was just one click away....